# Add a value at a given index without removing

Tags: arrays, bash

I really don't know how to use bash and I have a problem. I usualy use python so I don't know how to do without list. How can I add a value in an array without removing the default value.

```
myArray=(5 6 13 14)
```

For exemple, I would like to add 9 at the index 2 and I wan to get this :

```
myArray=(5 6 9 13 14)
```

And not this :

```
myArray=(5 6 9 14)
```

Obviously, doing `myArray[2]=9` doesn't works. I could add it and move everything else from 1 to left but I am trying to do something optimized so if there is a solution without loop, I would like to know it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use slices to grab the before and after parts of the array, then construct a new array.

```
n=2
myArray=( "${myArray[@]:0:n}" 9 "${myArray[@]:n}")
```

Asymptotically, it's no more efficient that writing the loop, but at least the shell handles the loop for you internally.

Comment: You beat me to it. But it is nice to know that this is not more efficient than writing the loop.

Comment: Can you be more precise @chepner ? What is the and the n ? Because I tried and it doesn't works

Comment: the `n` is the variable in the first line of his code: in an indexed array, the contents of the `[index]` is evaluated in arithmetic context, and in bash arithmetic expressions, you can refer to shell variables without the `$`